# VBA excel problemas para obtener fecha actual

Tags: excel, vba

Que tal como estan recientemente tengo un problema con un macro al obtener la fecha y el año actual, explico el macro.
Tengo un codigo para obtener un plan de pagos el cual introduzco cantidad, interes tiempo en meses y la fecha en el formaro dia/mes/año, pero al introducir la fecha el codigo deberia empezar la fecha comienza en 0/1/1900, lo revise detalladamente pero aun asi sigue comenzando desde esa fecha a continuacion subo el codigo:

```
Sub GenerarPlanPagos1()
Dim prestamo As Double
Dim interes As Double
Dim meses As Integer
Dim tasaInteres As Double
Dim pagoMensual As Double
Dim pagoTotal As Double
Dim i As Integer

' Ingresar los valores del préstamo, la tasa de interés y el número de meses
prestamo = CDbl(Range("B2").Value)
interes = CDbl(Range("B3").Value)
meses = CInt(Range("B4").Value)

' Calcular la tasa de interés mensual
tasaInteres = interes / 100 / 12

' Calcular el pago mensual
pagoMensual = WorksheetFunction.Pmt(tasaInteres, meses, -prestamo)

' Calcular el pago total
pagoTotal = pagoMensual * meses

' Limpiar la hoja de cálculo
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Cells.ClearContents

' Agregar encabezados
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Range("A10").Value = "Mes"
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Range("B10").Value = "Fecha de Pago"
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Range("C10").Value = "Pago Mensual"
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Range("D10").Value = "Saldo Restante"

' Obtener la fecha de inicio del préstamo
Dim fechaInicio As Date
Dim fechaTexto As String
fechaTexto = Range("B5").Text
fechaTexto = Replace(fechaTexto, "/", "-") ' Cambiar el formato de "/" a "-"

On Error Resume Next ' Evitar errores si el formato de fecha no es válido
fechaInicio = CDate(fechaTexto)
On Error GoTo 0 ' Reactivar las notificaciones de error

If Not IsDate(fechaInicio) Then
    MsgBox "El formato de fecha ingresado en la celda B5 no es válido. Por favor, ingresa la fecha en el formato 'día/mes/año' (por ejemplo, 01/06/2023 para el 1 de junio de 2023).", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

' Obtener el año, mes y día de la fecha de inicio
Dim añoInicio As Integer
Dim mesInicio As Integer
Dim diaInicio As Integer
añoInicio = Year(fechaInicio)
mesInicio = Month(fechaInicio)
diaInicio = Day(fechaInicio)

' Obtener el año actual
Dim añoActual As Integer
añoActual = Year(Date)

' Llenar el plan de pagos
Dim fila As Integer
fila = 11 ' Celda desde donde se empezará a llenar el plan de pagos
Dim fechaPago As Date
Dim saldoRestante As Double

fechaPago = DateSerial(añoInicio, mesInicio, diaInicio)

For i = 1 To meses
    Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Cells(fila, 1).Value = i
    Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Cells(fila, 2).Value = fechaPago
    Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Cells(fila, 2).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Cells(fila, 3).Value = pagoMensual
    saldoRestante = prestamo - (pagoMensual * i)
    Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Cells(fila, 4).Value = saldoRestante
    
    ' Aumentar la fecha de pago al siguiente mes
    fechaPago = DateSerial(Year(fechaPago), Month(fechaPago) + 1, diaInicio)
    fila = fila + 1 ' Aumentar la fila para el siguiente registro
Next i

' Agregar el total del pago
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Range("A" & fila).Value = "Total"
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Range("B" & fila).Value = ""
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Range("C" & fila).Value = pagoTotal
Worksheets("Plan de Pagos").Range("D" & fila).Value = ""
End Sub
```

Alguna sugerencia si tengo algun error o algo que le falte al codigo seria de mucha ayuda Gracias

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Qué parte de tu código falla? ¿Dónde se produce el error que mencionas? No podemos reproducirlo porque falta información. En cualquier caso, para obtener la fecha actual puedes usar [Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function)